# What is the significance of a graph exhibiting the delta property?

Tags: graph-theory, artificial-intelligence

In class about AI we are studying graph searches. Here, we defined the "delta" property to mean that `c(n,m)≥δ>0` for each `(n,m)` edge in the graph where `c(n,m)` is the weight of the edge connecting vertices `n` and `m`. We defined a *δ-graph* as a weighted, directed graph exhibiting the δ property and having a finite number of outgoing edges. In a lot of theorems we explicitly state that "the theorem is true for δ-graphs", but I don't quite see why this kind of graph is so important for such tasks. Can you explain what the significance of these properties is?

Comment: "having a finite number of outgoing edges  **from each vertex**"

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake. It has to be true for all the edges, you're right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is important because it makes it impossible to have arbitrarily long paths of small weights.

In other words, for every weight $w$ there is a length $l$ such that every path of weight less than $w$ has length at most $l$.

The other important property is that every vertex has a finite number of neighbours.

these two properties guarantee the following:

- For every two vertices $u$ and $v$ there exists a path of minimum length from $u$ to $v$ (or no paths exist)
- the path of minimum length can be computed using brute force

Comment: Thank you! I don't quite understand how a lower bound for weights prevents arbitrarily long paths of small weights. Can you elaborate on that a bit more please?

Comment: if a path has length $l$ then the weight is at least $\delta l$, so we can give bounds for the weight with respect to the length

Comment: Sorry I might be a bit tired :D I see how the minimum length of $\delta$l gives us a lower bound, but how does it prevent an arbitrary lenght (~how does this provide an upper bound for the length)?